# How to select ID of several children in an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ul element where I drag and drop li's elements from another list. I want to get the id of the li I dropped and print these id's in a div after pressing a button.

I tried this :

```
$(".validate-btn").click(function(){
var Id = $("ul#sortable3").children().attr('id');
$('.text-id').text(Id);
});
```

With this code I can just print the Id of the first li I have dropped. I need help to get the Id's of several li's.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I need help to get the Id's of several li's.*

You can use [**.map()**](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

> Description: Pass each element in the current matched set through a function, producing a new jQuery object containing the return value.
>
> As the return value is a jQuery object, which contains an array, it's very common to call .get() on the result to work with a basic array.

Use

```
var arr = $("ul#sortable3").children().map(function () {
    return this.id; //You can also use $(this).attr('id')
}).get(); //Result in array
var values = arr.join(); //in string
```

Comment: Works perfectly using:

$(".validate-btn").click(function(){
 var arr = $("ul#sortable3").children().map(function () {
     return this.id; 
 }).get();
 $('.text-id').text(arr);
});

(I do not know how to highlight code in comment, if someone can edit)

Thanks for your help

Comment: @ThibaultBouveur use the backtick `\`` character. The help link explains this if you forget.